Скачал проект соцсети с гитхаба, но не получается подключиться к БД
Захотелось мне создать свою соцсеть. Я установил локальный хост MAMP, нашел на гите какие то исходники, подходящие мне: https://github.com/iPynch/Simple-PHP-Social-Network-Website
Закинул в htdocs, вроде как ура, открылось окошко с регистрацией. Пробую зарегистрироваться - ничего не происходит. Залогинится - аналогично. Путем метода гуглотыка нашел что можно вручную создать запись в базе данных с моим аккаунтом. Создал, пытаюсь залогинится с этими данными, опять ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так? Подскажите пожалуйста, как вообще я должен дебажить это? Где лог, где консоль выполнения программы? Где это смотреть?
Я бы рад предоставить больше информации, но я даже не понимаю где ее искать.
p.s Создание нового аккаунта тоже не работает. Подозреваю, нету связи с базой данных. Но все возвращается к прежнему: где я могу отдебажить это?
Я работаю на данный момент через EmEditor, без установки специализированных многогиговых сред разработки.


Проект последний раз обновлялся 7 лет назад... Учитывая вопросы, вы учерены, что стоит начинать изучать вэб разработку сразу с готового проекта 7 летней давности? Возможно вам стоит почитаь про PHP для начала, а уже потом переходить к большому проекту

Я имею довольно неплохой опыт разработки на java и в принципе синтаксис и основы php мне тоже известны. Но на начальном уровне, буквально простейшие страницы делал и просто в блокноте, не связываясь с базами данных, специализированными средами и сложными сценариями.
Я сейчас все таки установил среду phpstorm для хотя бы какого то дебага и попробовал запустить проект там. Собственно, мои предположения подтвердились, что что то не так со связью сайта и БД. Хотя может быть так и будет, учитывая что я запускаю из среды разработки, которую я точно не привязывал к базе данных никак.
Ну а этот проект выглядит довольно простым с точки зрения взять и переделать его под свои нужды. Но для начала я пытаюсь его заставить работать...

Итак, мне есть что добавить. Конечно, потыкавшись туда-сюда, я все таки пришел к решению что надо начинать с основ. Подробно изучив основы PHP я приступил к делу. Первым делом мне надо было написать классы для регистрации. Короче, грубо говоря, спустя несколько часов тыканий и гугления я пришел к следующему.

Создал базу данных в phpMyAdmin
Создал базовые классы для регистрации и авторизации
Создал класс, который по идее должен создавать запросы в БД при регистрации\авторизации.
И тут меня поджидала ошибка PDO - could not find driver

Прикрепляю код:
 `<?php

// Настройки подключения к базе данных
$host = 'localhost'; 
$db = 'retrogramdb';
$user = 'myname'; 
$pass = 'mypass'; 

// DSN (Data Source Name) для подключения к базе данных
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=3306;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4"; 
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, 
];

try {
    // Создание подключения к базе данных
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    echo "Подключение к базе данных успешно установлено."; 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Обработка ошибок подключения
    die("Ошибка подключения к базе данных: " . $e->getMessage());
}
`

К слову, тестовое подключение среды разработки к базе данных прошло без запинки. А вот сам config.php, по какой то причине выдает ошибку. Уже чего только не перепробовал: проверять что включен pdo в php.ini, что пароли, порты совпадают, отключал брендмауэр, настраивал конфигурацию запуска. Ничего не помогает. При попытке подключится получаю все эту ошибку. Уже и не знаю что дальше делать (
p.s отвечу на некоторые комментарии: я из тех людей кто видит что то страшное, большое и меня просто пугает разбираться в этом. Поэтому я не стал дальше пробовать через плагины, движки пытаться создать то что мне надо. Исключительно с нуля.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Дубликат вопроса Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?

Как дебажить и искать ошибки ↑↑↑

Проект последний раз обновлялся 7 лет назад... Учитывая вопросы, вы учерены, что стоит начинать изучать вэб разработку сразу с готового проекта 7 летней давности? Возможно вам стоит почитаь про PHP для начала, а уже потом переходить к большому проекту

"работаю на данный момент через EmEditor, без установки специализированных многогиговых сред разработки" --- значит смотри поддерживает ли он какие-то плагины для дебага. Или рассмотри например хотя бы Visual Studio Code. Если ничего не устраивает, тогда дебажить не сможешь... А основы отладки описаны выше, со способами нахождения ошибок

Оказывается, для того, чтоб написать свой Facebook, надо просто захотеть. Ох уж этот Цукерберг... он хотел, а мы все нет.

Что я делаю не так? используете "какой-то проект многолетней давности". именно это, собственно не так. если сильно хочется войти в клепание соц сеток, без предварительного погружения в мат.часть, смотрите топ 5 актуальных CMS и выбираете одну из них. обязательно с живым форумом по ней, желательно на том языке на котором можете общаться(даже если её readme окажется недостаточно понятен, будет у кого спросить подробности). если такой вход не нравится, можно поискать учебник-инструкцию из серии "пишем свою CMS на PHP с нуля". ну а чтоб не сильно велосипедить гляньте еще yii \ laravel

Что вопрос, что ответы - просто сказка "Я купил готовый борщ, разогрел в микроволновки, но вдруг оказалось что я не могу его съесть - в доме нету ложки. потыкавшись туда-сюда, я все таки пришел к решению что надо сварить уху. Но вот проблема, в доме нету рыбы".

Автор, вы можете объяснить, зачем при ошибке "could not find driver" проверять что пароли совпадают? Вот какая может быть логика в этом? В этом сообщении об ошибке хоть слово написано про пароль?

$host = 'localhost'; - сюда нечего вставлять не надо!
$db = 'retrogramdb'; - вставь имя базы данных 
$user = 'myname';  - вставь имя пользователя базы данных
$pass = 'mypass'; - вставь пароль имя пользователя базы данных

Надеюсь помог!
И еще! Возможно, надо установить более старую версию MySQL или PHP

У автора вопроса вроде бы проблемы с подключением драйвера БД и отладкой, данный ответ не совсем по существу.

Не очень понятен смысл этого ответа. Автор вопроса прекрасно и так знает, что куда писать, ему не надо это подсказывать.

Возможно немножко не понял, но лучше ему перейти на ispmanager

"Я установил локальный хост MAMP" и в каком месте ему надо перейти на ispmanager?
